# Circuit to solve algebra problem?

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am trying to get the hang of op amps and have a few questions about circuits that solve algebra problems.  I would like to solve two problems where \$X\$ is an input voltage and \$Y\$ is an output voltage.  The two (independent) equations are:
$$Y=X/10+11$$
$$Y=X^2$$

For the first, I think the answer would be to start off with a buffer of the input, use a resistor voltage divider from the buffer output and the run the result through a summing amplifier that adds 11.

For the second, I think it would be to run the input through an integrator circuit to get \$X^2/2\$ and then put that through a non inverting amp with a gain of 2.

The input would be between 0 and 5 volts for both of these.

Do op amps solve problems this way?  No present access to a Sim or breadboard but can try this out at a later time.

Comment: Addition and scaling are easily achieved with op amps. Multiplication is another animal.

Comment: http://www.utdallas.edu/~mtacca/courses/EE3150/Spring-2012/AD633.pdf

Comment: Yikes, multiplier chip IS expensive.  Sounds like it might be easier to use a/d, perform the operation and the d/a again.  So in short it looks like op amps can fairly easily handle addition and subtraction, resistor dividers can handle division.  But multiplication and powers through analog circuits take quite a bit more effort.  The speed would operate below 100khz, never into the mhz.  I'd have to crack open some refresher material on logrythms, but considering that route, can anyone recommend reading material around transistors for analog operations such as logrythms?  I'm guessing this ap

Comment: Nice question!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you *could* do something like that. The 'answer' (second case) would only be present for an instant since the integration with respect to time would continue, and you'd have to have a way to reset the capacitor (initial condition) and grab that voltage after exactly x seconds.

You could do it statically with log and antilog amplifiers (using the logarithmic property of transistors plus op-amps).

\$\frac{x^2}{2}\$ = 0.5\$e^{2 log_e(x)}\$

Easier said (or written) than done, and has 'interesting' complications if x is negative, zero or even very small.

Or use a multiplier chip (expensive).

Even at MHz you can do this digitally, so that tends to be the way people roll these days.